# Zend_Cache with Memcachier

Tags: zend-framework, caching, memcached

Can I use memcachier with ZendFramework 1.12 ?

The provider that I am useing(AppFog) only offers Memcachier (Memcached is comming soon from 10 Months) And My app will need a lot of caching when it starts. I don't want to stick with APC so I have no other good alternative.

Comment: Lol I haven't tried that option, but wanted to know if there is some workaround that, because the memcachier uses SASL authentication that is not supported by the default memcached class and I have to use a third party class in a regular coding, but in SF I have no idea.. Up for the funny comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is just a half answer right now, I'll try to figure out the rest. I work for MemCachier by the way, so please shoot us an email on support@memcachier.com if you have more questions.

PHP includes two memcache bindings by default: memcache and memcached. The first one (memcache) is its own implementation of the memcache procotol, while the second one (memcached) is a php binding to the libmemcached C++ library.

The memcached binding for php does support SASL these days (since version 2.0.0). Sadly it isn't documented. It also is an optional part of the memcached module, so you'll need to make sure it is compiled on your machine (or AppFog) with the SASL support enabled. The steps to do that roughly are:

1. Install libmemcached. I used version 1.0.14.
2. Install php-memcached. Make sure to pass the "--enable-memcached-sasl" option to it when running ./configure.
3. When building both of these you can sanity check the output of "./configure" to make sure that SASL support is indeed enabled, sadly right now it can be tricky.
4. Edit you php.ini file. Put the following line into it:

   ```
   [memcached]
   memcached.use_sasl = 1
   ```

I did all of this on OSX 10.8 using homebrew. If that is the case for you the following should work:

```
$ brew install libmemcached
$ brew edit php54-memcached 
    // you'll need to add the line: 
       args << "--enable-memcached-sasl"
    // to the brew file.
$ brew install php54-memcached
```

Now to actually use SASL support, here is a test file that demonstrates it and is a good sanity check.

```
<?php 
/**
 * Test of the PHP Memcached extension.
 */

error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE); 

$use = ini_get("memcached.use_sasl");
$have = Memcached::HAVE_SASL;
echo "Have SASL? $have\n";
echo "Using SASL? $use\n\n";

$mc = new Memcached(); 

$mc->setOption(Memcached::OPT_BINARY_PROTOCOL, true);

$mc->setSaslAuthData("user-1", "pass");

$mc->addServer("localhost", 11211); 

$mc->set("foo", "Hello!"); 
$mc->set("bar", "Memcached..."); 

$arr = array( 
    $mc->get("foo"), 
      $mc->get("bar") 
    ); 
var_dump($arr); 
?>
```

Adapting this to work in the Zend Framework is unknown to me right now. I'm not familiar with it so may take me some time to install and figure out. It seems very doable though given one of the backends works with SASL auth.